# Vectorise a string

Tags: python-2.7, svm, sklearn-pandas

Im a python noob but trying to vectorise a string with no luck. So far I extract data from an article from a URL and now im trying to clasfiy that article but so far its not working.

> (keep getting the error: raise AttributeError(attr + " not
>   found")AttributeError: lower not found)

Nothing out there seems to be helping either.

```
    url = input("Paste the webiste containing the article you want to analise here: ");
print "Analysing Webpage"
#Gets the URL from the extension
#Goose loaded
g = Goose()
#Extract the text and feed it to the classifier
article = g.extract(url=url)
article = article.cleaned_text
article = clean(article)
article =str(article)
print "Vectorising Text"
article = article.split();
vect = CountVectorizer(min_df=0., max_df=1.0)
X = vect.fit_transform(article)
X.toarray()
X = vect.transform(X).toarray()
print X
print "Predicting Political Bias"
loaded_model = pickle.load(open("text_clf_svm.pkl", 'rb'))
predicted_svm = loaded_model.predict(X)
print predicted_svm
```

Any kind of help or indication is very welcomed, and thanked =)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you apply a *fit_transform* to your text. This result to a different X matrix to the one you/someone trained the classifier on. You need to have both "aligned".

In your case, you have the word "lower" in your X matrix but the model has been trained on a matrix without this word.

In your case, either you have the **CountVectorizer** model used to train the model and you have to apply only a *transform*, or you should use *fit_transform* but on a full corpus to train after the model and use it later in production.

I hope it helps,

Regards,
Nicolas